# Unity build for Android fails on Gradle error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

Since today, I suddenly get the following error when trying to build my Unity game for Android, it looks like he sees 2 times the android.arch.core file, but there is only one. I already tried deleting all imported packages and resimport them again, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know the problem?

Error: https://gist.github.com/RobinKuiper/3b75a5f15c629c2e39456515ffc69319

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Vungle Unity plugin conflicts with the Admob Unity plugin.